# Unity: Failed because this command failed to write the following output files

Tags: unity-game-engine, failed-installation

i need help!
Unity version 2021.3.16f1 is installed in my school's computer lab (Windows systems with IServ). We have been using Unity for many years, this error has been occurring since last week and never before.

On 19 PCs an **empty 3D core project** is created and immediately these error messages appear, but only on about half of the PCs. On the others everything runs smoothly.

```
Failed because this command failed to write the following output files:
Library\Bee\artifacts\mvdfrm\UnityEngine.UI.ref.dll_08FEAA520A2EFD60.mvfrm
Failed because this command failed to write the following output files:
Library\Bee\artifacts\mvdfrm\UnityEngine.TestRunner.ref.dll_E55D0F7C63F01D9E.mvfrm
Failed because this command failed to write the following output files:
Library\Bee\artifacts\mvdfrm\UnityEditor.TestRunner.ref.dll_193EC4CE382CBFB3.mvfrm
Failed because this command failed to write the following output files:
Library\Bee\artifacts\mvdfrm\UnityEditor.UI.ref.dll_4C98D3F7040CD4F5.mvfrm
Failed because this command failed to write the following output files:
Library\Bee\artifacts\mvdfrm\Unity.Services.Core.ref.dll_131AC9C5EC6E6517.mvfrm
Failed because this command failed to write the following output files:
Library\Bee\artifacts\mvdfrm\Unity.Services.Core.Internal.ref.dll_A02B3542C15F550A.mvfrm
Failed because this command failed to write the following output files:
Library\Bee\artifacts\mvdfrm\Unity.TextMeshPro.ref.dll_84A4293DBDD182DB.mvfrm
Failed because this command failed to write the following output files:
Library\Bee\artifacts\mvdfrm\Unity.Settings.Editor.ref.dll_7F5B154C05A780B0.mvfrm
Failed because this command failed to write the following output files:
Library\Bee\artifacts\mvdfrm\Unity.PlasticSCM.Editor.ref.dll_257AEB342BE77856.mvfrm
Failed because this command failed to write the following output files:
Library\Bee\artifacts\mvdfrm\Unity.Services.Core.Telemetry.ref.dll_FA20132DD923A4D2.mvfrm
Failed because this command failed to write the following output files:
Library\Bee\artifacts\mvdfrm\Unity.VisualScripting.Core.Editor.ref.dll_EDC8690F57C5BDFD.mvfrm
Failed because this command failed to write the following output files:
Library\Bee\artifacts\mvdfrm\Unity.VisualScripting.Core.ref.dll_D75DF4EA1AFE54F4.mvfrm
Failed because this command failed to write the following output files:
Library\Bee\artifacts\mvdfrm\Unity.VisualScripting.Flow.ref.dll_1E6ED5409D07C9A3.mvfrm
Failed because this command failed to write the following output files:
Library\Bee\artifacts\mvdfrm\Unity.VisualScripting.State.ref.dll_D91762B7076BE462.mvfrm
Failed because this command failed to write the following output files:
Library\Bee\artifacts\mvdfrm\Unity.VisualScripting.Flow.Editor.ref.dll_6AF951BE66A4493E.mvfrm
Failed because this command failed to write the following output files:
Library\Bee\artifacts\mvdfrm\Unity.Services.Core.Configuration.ref.dll_9A0B0462DB47136F.mvfrm
Failed because this command failed to write the following output files:
Library\Bee\artifacts\mvdfrm\Unity.Timeline.ref.dll_621CDDF9C514DF8F.mvfrm
Failed because this command failed to write the following output files:
Library\Bee\artifacts\mvdfrm\Unity.Services.Core.Environments.ref.dll_7E0AC2CDE81D9C6D.mvfrm
Failed because this command failed to write the following output files:
Library\Bee\artifacts\mvdfrm\Unity.TestTools.CodeCoverage.Editor.OpenCover.Model.ref.dll_D3B9364D6FB03093.mvfrm
Failed because this command failed to write the following output files:
Library\Bee\artifacts\mvdfrm\Unity.Services.Core.Scheduler.ref.dll_EE2AFA3B402F70E4.mvfrm
Failed because this command failed to write the following output files:
Library\Bee\artifacts\mvdfrm\Unity.Services.Core.Environments.Internal.ref.dll_E1932F3567E8EA54.mvfrm
Failed because this command failed to write the following output files:
Library\Bee\artifacts\mvdfrm\Unity.Services.Core.Device.ref.dll_EC89AF6B778C7413.mvfrm
Failed because this command failed to write the following output files:
Library\Bee\artifacts\mvdfrm\Unity.Services.Core.Networking.ref.dll_9223E05EC4657081.mvfrm
Failed because this command failed to write the following output files:
Library\Bee\artifacts\mvdfrm\Unity.Services.Core.Configuration.Editor.ref.dll_FF09FAD520872032.mvfrm
Failed because this command failed to write the following output files:
Library\Bee\artifacts\mvdfrm\Unity.Services.Core.Editor.ref.dll_CCD0CF61C5D7A10A.mvfrm
Failed because this command failed to write the following output files:
Library\Bee\artifacts\mvdfrm\Unity.TestTools.CodeCoverage.Editor.OpenCover.Mono.Reflection.ref.dll_E668CD773429A040.mvfrm
Failed because this command failed to write the following output files:
Library\Bee\artifacts\mvdfrm\Unity.Services.Core.Threading.ref.dll_F1D7894C57B2A611.mvfrm
Failed because this command failed to write the following output files:
Library\Bee\artifacts\mvdfrm\Unity.Services.Core.Registration.ref.dll_0EE1D1878B496356.mvfrm
```

I have already tried many things:

- Restart
- De/reinstall
- run as admin
- Re-import packages
- tried it with 2021.3.19f1
- Import "healthy" project from another computer
- change the project path from iserv to C:

Nothing has helped.

The only thing that has worked so far is to delete the entire \mvdfrm\ folder.... But I don't know if that is needed for anything, or can I delete this folder without any consequences???

Can someone help me? It's just super annoying...

Comment: I've seen issues with projects saved on external drives, are you creating/saving the project on the same drive as installation?

Comment: @Barreto Not by default, but I tried creating a new project in the same save path of the installation, that didn't work either. I have now deleted the folder...